# Why is the 'Use of "shift" without parentheses is ambiguous' warning issued by Perl?

Tags: perl, syntax, warnings

Does anyone know what parsing or precedence decisions resulted in the warning 'Use of "shift" without parentheses is ambiguous' being issued for code like:

```
shift . 'some string';

# and not

(shift) . 'some string'; # or
shift() . 'some string';
```

Is this intentional to make certain syntactic constructs easier?  Or is it merely an artifact of the way perl's parser works?

Note: this is a discussion about language design, not a place to suggest

```
"@{[shift]}some string"
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

With `use diagnostics`, you get the helpful message:

```
    Warning: Use of "shift" without parentheses is ambiguous at (eval
        9)[/usr/lib/perl5/5.8/perl5db.pl:628] line 2 (#1)
    (S ambiguous) You wrote a unary operator followed by something that
    looks like a binary operator that could also have been interpreted as a
    term or unary operator.  For instance, if you know that the rand
    function has a default argument of 1.0, and you write

        rand + 5;

    you may THINK you wrote the same thing as

        rand() + 5;

    but in actual fact, you got

        rand(+5);

    So put in parentheses to say what you really mean.
```

The fear is you could write something like `shift .5` and it will be parsed like `shift(0.5)`.

Comment: I would upvote, but "my daily vote limit is reached." I think that's a bug, because I think SO went down for a few minutes right on the time when it was supposed to reset, so I'm being penalized for having voted yesterday.

Comment: in the case of rand (;$) i can see a case for the warning, however, with shift there doesn't seem to be, since shift's prototype (;\@) would prevent a string or number from being a valid argument

Comment: @Eric Strom: this error comes from the tokenizer, which isn't that smart.  Unrelatedly, shift's prototype isn't really (;\@), since that would make it a list operator and it is in fact a unary operator.

Comment: you mean prototype is lying to me... the horror

Comment: no wait, why would (;\@) make it a list operator, i would interpret that prototype as taking zero arguments, or one which must be an @ array

Comment: @Eric Strom: it just does; anything other than ($) or (_) is a list operator.  Try with different prototypes:  perl -we'sub foo (;\@) {} print foo @a, 1, 2, 3'

Comment: @ysth - learn something new every day, i dont think i've ever tried prototyping a sub with the expectation of getting it to work like shift.  Most of my work with prototypes has been either with (&@) type prototypes or ($) for unary operators.  Anyone know if the upcoming revisions to perl5 are going to adjust this parsing 'quirk', or backport any more of the builtin magic to user space?

Comment: This points to something that is bothering me: The fad of leaving out extra parentheses on functions for _clarity_. For example, there's a difference between `join ":", @foo . $bar` and `join  ( ":", @foo ) . bar`. In the first, I am concatenating  `@foo . $bar` and then doing the join. It's as if I did this: `join ( ":", ( @foo . $bar ) )`. However, since I'm not use to writing parentheses when using `join`, and that works 99% of the time, I probably won't catch the error. It's always that last 1% that hides in wait and bites you in the _Southern Regions_ when you least expect it.

Answer (score 8):

Ambiguous doesn't mean truly ambiguous, just ambiguous as far as the parser had determined.
`shift .` in particular is "ambiguous" because `.` can start a term (e.g. `.123`) or an operator,
so it doesn't know enough to decide whether what follows is shift's operand or an operator for which shift() is the operand (and the parser isn't smart enough to know that: a) the `.`
isn't the start of such a term or b) `.123` isn't a valid operand for shift).